# Xpath evaluate count in "[ ]"

Tags: java, xml, xpath, evaluate

i have class with the members   -

```
private Document myDoc;
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
```

i try to use `evaluate` function  -

```
Object result = xpath.evaluate(expression, this.myDoc,
                XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

when `expression` is a `string` s.t

```
expression = "inventory/book[" +
                "count(following-sibling::book/price/text()=14.95)=0 ]"  ;
```

and i get the follow exception  -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can not convert #BOOLEAN to a NodeList!
```

even when i change `XPathConstants.NODESET` to `XPathConstants.NUMBER` i get same exception . thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
expression = "inventory/book[" +
         "count(following-sibling::book[price/text()=14.95])=0]";
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the few cases where XPath 1.0 returns a type error: the argument to the count() function is a boolean expression (path/a/b = 14.94), and count() requires it to be a node-set. (In XPath 2.0 the count of a single boolean is 1, so your query would run successfully, and give wrong answers).